# Add an async code inside a redux action generator without returning a function and using redux-thunk?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

Without using redux-thunk, I want to add an object(expense) to firebase realtime database inside the action generator function before returning the action itself. I don't see the need to redux-thunk if I am able to execute the async function.
Here is the code in src/actions/expenses.js

```
export const  addExpense = ({description= '', note= '', createdAt= 0, amount= 0} = {}) => {
const expense = {
    id: uuidv4(),
    description,
    note,
    createdAt,
    amount
}

const db = firebase.database()
db.ref('expenses').push(expense)

return {
    type: 'ADD',
    expense
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

While it would technically work, this way you are making harder to write tests (see [this example](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#action-creators)).

If you don't care about tests... you probably didn't need redux in the first place

Comment: I read the docs it does not mention that using thunk makes testing easier

Comment: It doesn't, using pure action creators does

Comment: but the same goes for thunks, they are not pure, it is even the purpose of them to include async functions belonging to APIs, therefore they are also impure functions.

Comment: Yes, what I meant was simply that if action creator is not pure you cannot safely write something like
`assertEqual( addItem(item), { type: 'ADD_ITEM', payload: item })`
or
`assertEqual( itemsReducer([], addItem(item)), [item])`.

Redux thunk doesn't help you testing effects, for that you'd need something like redux-saga